# Which way should I write a New Mongoose Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm wondering if there is a difference between these two pieces of code or if one method is better than the other?

Or something different?

```
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  const fruitSchema = new Schema({});
  const veggieSchema = new Schema({});

or 

  const fruitSchema = mongoose.Schema({});
  const veggieSchema = mongoose.Schema({});
```

Comment: I prefer to use the former. Just caches the `mongoose.Schema` object which improves your code's performance, right?

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. `mongoose.Schema` is a constructor function but when invoking it as normal function it will internally create the schema using `new`. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L77).